# Main use of Spawn class and the spawn method in ExpectJ

Tags: java, linux

I'm still not able to spawn the process.Is there something i need to do somewhere else? Here's my code-

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

import expectj.*;

public class Trial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    ExpectJ exp = new ExpectJ(20);
    String command = "java /root/Interactive_Response/MissionExpectJ/bin Hello";//Hello is the class in which i've written the same details but using sysout and sysin statements.
    Spawn s;
    try {
        s = exp.spawn(command);

        s.expect("Name: ");//enter the name
        s.send("aaaa\n");
        s.expect("password: ");
        s.send("aaa");
        System.out.println("Welcome!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

In the below exception,"Interactive_Response" is my workspace and "MissionExpectJ" is my project.

**OUTPUT**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /root/Interactive_Response/MissionExpectJ/bin

java.io.IOException: End of stream reached, no match found

```
at expectj.Spawn.expect(Spawn.java:321)

at expectj.Spawn.expect(Spawn.java:142)

at expectj.Spawn.expect(Spawn.java:370)
```

### at Trial.main(Trial.java:14)

The below code is the old one..

I'm trying to spawn a process using spawn() method. But I'm getting a IOException. "THOUGH MY CODE IS INCOMPLETE", this is what I'm exactly trying to do. Pls let me know if i'm wrong (or I'd rather say "please let me know where I'm going wrong").I'm trying to use ExpectJ tool to succesfully execute this.

```
import java.io.*;

import expectj.*;

public class Trial {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ExpectJ exp = new ExpectJ(20);
    String command = "echo $PPID";
    System.out.println("The command you entered is " + command);

    Spawn s = exp.spawn(command);//It doesnt display the PPID
    s.expect("Name: ");//Here is where my problem starts.I don't understand what i'm missing here
    s.send("aaaa\n");
    s.expect("password: ");
    s.send("aaa");
    System.out.println("End of session!");
}
```

}

**OUTPUT**

The command you entered is echo $PPID

$PPID

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: End of stream reached, no match found

```
at expectj.Spawn.expect(Spawn.java:321)

at expectj.Spawn.expect(Spawn.java:142)

at expectj.Spawn.expect(Spawn.java:370)

at Trial.main(Trial.java:12)
```

Comment: Please post your **stack trace**

Comment: @brian: can u plz give me the corrected code?If i'm not troubling you..

Comment: I dont understand what exactly is going wrong here..I'm new to this concept..Plz help me out here..

Comment: i've posted the stack trace now after the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you would expect:

- it calls `/bin/echo` which outputs `$PPID`
- It then throws an exception telling you that your match failed.

$PPID is a shell special variable. `/bin/echo` knows nothing about it and is simply going to output it as text. After that, I'm not sure why you think you'd be getting the output you're looking for (`Name`, `password:`) from `echo`.

Comment: oh..I was under the impression that it would show the PPID of the process..cuz it did when i executed the command directlyon the terminal

Comment: That's because the shell substitutes the parent process id for $PPID. You don't have a shell here.

Comment: Ok i'm not concerned about PPID.My main intension is to interact with the system through terminal using ExpectJ..Any suggestions how i could do that?

Comment: You're using it just fine. If you started a command that output "Name: " then the exception wouldn't be thrown and your code would then continue and send ""aaaa\n" to the spawned process and so forth.

Comment: -I've written a Java Program (which is done!)
-I need to execute it through a shell script (which is also done!)
-I need to interact with the system here (Thats where i'm facing problems)

Comment: No luck...I've made some changes above..Pls take a look and let me know where I'm going wrong..